# Using Calculate Field in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

[image]I need to use calculate field to carry a date of a table to another that has a field in common (`MATERIALES`). I need `VALOR=Indice_R`. I am trying with

```
def RecarI(tipo1,id,tipo2):
    tipo1=tipo2
    id=tipo1
    if ('id=0'):
        return  1
    elif ('id=1'):
        return  2
    elif ('id=2'):
        return  3
    elif ('id=3'):
        return  1
    elif ('id=4'):
        return 1
    elif ('id=5'):
        return  1
    elif ('id=6'):
        return 2
RecarI( !Recarga.MATERIALES! , !Recarga.OID!, !Geologia_LR.MATERIALES! )
```

but not working

[image].[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your ModelBuilder model? Is there a join existing between the two tables already?

Comment: yes, there are join

Comment: Why don't you just set `!Recarga.Indice_R! = !Geologia_LR.VALOR!`

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: Does that field calculation work if you manually join the two tables, outside of ModelBuilder? When you say it's not working, are you getting an error, or just no data copied?

Comment: Just no data copied, but i find the answer with your answer: Geologia_LR.Indice_R=!Recarga.VALOR!. i am sorry for my english and thank you for your help. and nice tu meet you i am antonio valencia from colombia and i am studying a specialization on GIS.

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't work because the calculation is just completely wrong.  You also expressed you question backwards.  You want to set Indice_R=Valor, not Valor=Indice_R.  This is a simple calculation if all you want to do is calculate the Valor value to the Indice_R field through a join.  Add field indexes to the MATERIALES fields on both datasets prior to doing the join.  Make adding the field index part of the script if either dataset it created by the script, otherwise do it once outside the model for permanent data.  Then the calculation is just done to output to the Geologia_LR.Indice_R field with a calculated value of:

!Recharga.VALOR!

If an error still occurs you are doing this on a shapefile (bad practice, use File Geodatabases and convert to other formats for export instead) and one or more records has no match in the join.  For that you may have to first select records that match through the join so that you only process the previous calculation on matching records or adjust the calculation to use a codeblock to check for Null values:

Parser: Python

use Codeblock: Checked

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def Recar1(Valor)
    if Valor == None:
       return -1
    else:
       return Valor
```

Geologia_LR.Indice_R:  Recar1(!Recharga.VALOR!)

Comment: i find the answer already. it was  Geologia_LR.Indice_R=!Recarga.VALOR!. only this on the field caculator. thank you.